# How to alert "#" value from url or hide it from URL with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question, for an example. I have this

```
<a href="#test1"> Test </a>
<a href="#test2"> Test 2 </a>
```

The Url is become something like this `siteurl/#test1` when i click `test` right ? then when you refresh the url it wont change right ?

So, I have two question. The first question, when i alert `test1` from the url with jquery and the second question how to hide the `#test1` from URL ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question this might be what you need to call alerts from the url `javascript:alert("Kode Javascript dari File Eksternal")`.
if you want to hidden this, you just click OK from the alert